# Ctypes callback function crashes after certain amount of calls

Tags: python, bluetooth, callback, ctypes

I m trying to wrap a bluetooth stack using Ctypes. The stack works asynchronously, user calls a function and recieves response with data in callback later. To handle the callback on the Python side I use a CFUNFTYPE mechanism as usual. Everything works fine I m able to send and receive data, use the whole API with all the structs almost as in C. The only problem is that after certain amount of callback calls (e.g. 275 packets received) it fails -it just stops receiving events or causes access violations, memory read and writes to random addresses. When I mirror the same implementation in C everything works fine so the problem must occur on the way to the Python.

**Python:**

```
callback_type = CFUNCTYPE(None, c_int, c_int, c_int, c_void_p)

def bt_callback(event, service_id, function_id, data):
   ....callback stuff here.....

# keep reference to function object
callback = callback_type(bt_callback)
```

And few lines below passing function object to the C side in Init function

```
status = BT_Init(byref(pSettings), byref(pStackSettings), callback)
```

where BT_Init ctypes declaration is as follows:

```
BT_Init = lib.Py_BT_Init
BT_Init.restype = c_int
BT_Init.argtypes = [POINTER(BT_Settings_t), POINTER(BT_StackSettings_t), callback_type]
```

I also have a simple C layer on the top of original API which allows me to experiment with different implementations, in case of BT_Init it just passes arguments to the original Init function

**C:**

```
int Py_BT_Init(BT_Settings_t * pSettings, BT_StackSettings_t *   pStackSettings, void * pyCallback)
{
    BTSTATUS_t status = BT_Init(pSettings, pStackSettings, pyCallback);
    return (int)status;
}
```

I have tested this code on three different platforms x86, ARM BeagleBone and even OMAP35x from TI with various Linux distributions and got the same results - crash after certain number of callback calls. The only difference was the number of successful iterations before crash. x86-275, ARM-374

What might be the reason of this? Is my function object garbage collected of is it related to some threading issue? Does anyone has an idea what it could be?